# How to install libnfc-doc-1.7.0 for MFOC

Tags: software-installation, libraries, nfc

I would like the MFOK to find the libnfc-doc file that is in my downloads so I can execute the ./configure "command"---> make --> sudo make install.

I always get the last line (after all others end by : yes) :

-->"checking for libnfc... no"

after typing :
---> "user:Downloads/mfoc-mfoc-O.10.7"

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm almost there to get the ACR122U-A9 to copy my RFID badge.

If you know any other workaround on windows/Mac OS to clone it without having to get to this hack it'll be even better !

Stay safe & thanks.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from repository by installing related packages with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libnfc-dev libnfc-bin libnfc-examples
```

These packages have [man-pages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libnfc-bin/filelist) [inside](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libnfc-examples/filelist).